# jQuery .focus() not firing

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to set a focus on the next input once the char limit has been reached on the first one. Both input are generated and the event keypress bound as follows :

```
 var newline = "<br /><div id=\"divRef" + i + "\" class=\"DivsRefList\">" +
                      "<b>Référence " + haszero + i + " : </b>" +
                      "<input type=\"text\" id=\"TBRef" + i + "n1\" class=\"TBsRefList\" style=\"width:50px;margin-right:5px;\" />" +
                      "<input type=\"text\" id=\"TBRef" + i + "n2\" class=\"TBsRefList\" style=\"width:40px;margin-right:5px;\" />" +
                      "<input type=\"text\" id=\"TBRef" + i + "n3\" class=\"TBsRefList\" style=\"width:40px;margin-right:5px;\" />" +
                      "</div>";
            $("#divRefList").append(newline);

            $("#TBRef" + i + "n1").on('keypress', function (e) {
                if (this.value.length > 3) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#TBRef" + i + "n2").focus();
                }
            });
```

When I reach the char limit on the field `TBRef1n1` the preventDefault works properly but the focus won't be set on the next field `TBRef1n2`.I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and I've tried both in Chrome and IE. I've tried to set a timeout before calling `.focus()` but nothing has worked so far.

[Here's a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3j1hkaay/3/)

Comment: Add a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) too, please? :)

Comment: @entiendoNull I've just tried in a jsfiddle and it works.. I'm clueless. I'm going to see if anything in the javascript interfer with the event.

Comment: add your fiddle to your post and let's have a look :)
Does your script trigger on document ready? Or when and how is the `newline` appended to `divRefList`?

Comment: @entiendoNull I added the jsfillde link. The control are not generated in the document ready. I create an number X of newline accroding to the value of another input. IF you input 3  it generates 3 newline and append them to the div divRefList (with the ID's/Class/Name etc. numerated properly)